# What is the difference between cmdline options --trace and --debug-output in cmake?

Tags: debugging, cmake, trace, difference, cmdline-args

Does the "--trace" option show more details than "--debug-output" does? cmake -h does not explain much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation seems to be pretty clear on that:

For `--debug-output` it

> prints extra information during the cmake run like stack traces with message(SEND_ERROR) calls.

And `--trace` flag simply makes CMake to print every command it is executing. It helps to see how loops or macros are executed, because commands are outputted in flattened form.

Comment: Which documentation are you referring to? 'cmake -h' says this "--debug-output               = Put cmake in a debug mode."

Comment: I found it: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/manual/cmake.1.html.